# Facing difficulty to store data from HTML5 storage to application database

Tags: javascript, html, session, browser-cache

I am trying to create a web application with HTML5 storage. Now I want to store data to client side using HTML5. I can store data to browser cache using

```
.setItem(key, value)
.getItem(key)
```

key word. Now I want to store data from local storage to application database. I want to know how can i store the local storage data in the session storage and then web application database.

Comment: HTML 5 session storage does not store anything in a "database" beyond temporary browser memory. HTML 5 session storage is deleted when the browser tab is closed. Local storage lasts longer and survives browser quit/restart, but is stored in browser's internet files.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: Hi Paul, thank u for your ans, but can you explain the process to solve this difficulty. some more..

Comment: If the application database is on the *web server*, and the data is in the browser cache, then the browser would need to send the data to the server somehow.  An AJAX request is the usual way to do that transmission.  There are other technologies in HTML 5 that can store a small database on the client, like webSQL and IndexedDB but webSQL was apparently abandoned and IndexedDB support is poor.  Books can be written on all of this, it is too broad a question unless you narrow the question by clicking edit.

Answer (score -1):

[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
sessionStorage.getItem('key')
```

by using this you can set the session.server said u can call the session object and you  can store it in data base .

```
 // Get the current session object, create one if new 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   String lastname=   session.getAttribute("key");
```

then you can store it in database

Comment: Hi Yugi! please tell me how to store these data to session storage.

Comment: what does seesion storage mean to you?

Comment: i modified the answer please check that @apache